# setopt listambiguous not setting the option

Tags: zsh

In ZSH I run this at the command line:

```
 $ setopt listambiguous
```

I then run `setopt` to get a list of current options:

```
 $ setopt
```

It's not in the list. Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `list_ambiguous` option is on by default, so `setopt listambiguous` changes nothing unless you've previously turned it off. A plain `setopt` doesn't display options whose setting is the default value.

Comment: @KevinBurke `set -o` shows all available options and their value. If you need a different format, look at the `options` parameter provided by the `zsh/parameter` module.